# Оптимизация приложения

Tags: java

Есть пример кода программы:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable 
{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    Thread t;

    MyPanel() {
        x= 0;
        y = 0;

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        while (true) {
            try {
                x+=10;
                repaint();
                t.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске на экран рисуется квадратик и который должен двигаться в право на 10 пикселей. Все запускается, все работает но есть одно но... Программа притормажывает. Как будто просто sleep() не правильно отрабатывает. Или может есть возможность оптимизировать код чтобы он не зависимо от машины на которой запускается отрабатывал без торможений. Кто может помочь подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: вы сами ставите максимальную производительность в десять кадров в секунду за счет sleep(100).

Comment: x+=5;
...
t.sleep(50);

Будет та же скорость в пикселей/секунду, но плавнее.

Comment: Используйте двойную буферизацию.

Comment: это с помощью BufferedStrategy?

Comment: я просто слышал где то что можно сделать так чтобы приложения работали одинаково на любых машин. может я ошибаюсь. Как то я работал в Unity3D и там есть прием такой чтобы программа работала в соответсвии с производительностью компа. т.е. чтобы не было такого что на компе по слабее она зависала, а на компе по лучше работала нормально.

Comment: чтобы вы понимали всю иронию судьбы то я объясню в чем ситуация. у меня сдох винт. денег на новый пока нету и пришлось ставить систему на внешний диск (USB 2.0 SilikonPower, Linux Mint 18 x64). Система работает хорошо, я даже не ожидал. Но вот такая простая программа работает с зависами. Хотя я пробовал на других компах и работает вроде норм все. Но вот на моем компе запускаю игрушку по тяжелее и работает норм. игрушка тоже на java. и я не могу понять как игра по тяжелее работает все ок. а кусок кода что я выше выложил зависает???